# Is it possible to submit a form with ViewChild in Angular5?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to submit a form with ViewChild in Angular5 code? How? 
I tried but it was not successful

HTML :

```
 <form #form="ngForm" (submit)="submitForm(form)" novalidate>
  <input required type="text" #codeRequest="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="requestModel.codeRequest" id="codeRequest" name="codeRequest"/>
 </form>

 <button (click)="func()"> </button>
```

TypeScript :

```
@ViewChild('form') form: ElementRef;
  constructor(){}

  func(){
    this.formStep2.nativeElement.submit();
  }

  submitForm(form: NgForm) {
    ... 
  }
```

Where is my problem؟

Comment: If you want to use Angular, use HttpClient for your http calls. If you want to use native submit, why would you use Angular ?

Comment: Please take a look at the Angular Doc... https://angular.io/guide/forms Edit: And maybe give your button the `type="submit"` and implement it inside your form.. ;)

Comment: thanks for help but, I know How can I use to submit in angular 5 . but I don't know How can I call a submit with ViewChild @ibenjelloun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to submit a form with a button(type=submit) outside the form you can do the following

define a model :

```
export interface Student {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

in app.component.ts:

```
  public model: Student;

  @ViewChild('form', { read: NgForm }) form: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setDefaultValueForModel();
  }

  saveForm($event: Event) {
    $event.preventDefault();

    if (this.form.valid) {
       console.log(this.form.value);
       alert('valid');
     } else {
     alert('invalid');
   }
}

setDefaultValueForModel() {
  this.model = {
    id: 0,
    name: ''
  };
```

and finally your app.component.html

```
   <form #form="ngForm" novalidate id="ngForm" (submit)="saveForm($event)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" required name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" #name="ngModel">
      <p *ngIf="name.invalid && name.touched">
        Family is required.
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div>
    <button type="submit" form="ngForm" [disabled]="!form.form.valid">
      Save
    </button>
  </div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfxw98)

Comment: I have a use case, where the submit button is in parent and parent's parent component. How do I submit the form (present in the leaf level) from it's parent and grand parent component? ViewChild is not workin for me. Here is the stackblitz link: https://angular-5-trigger-reactve-form-submission-from-parent-component.stackblitz.io

Comment: why `(submit)` instead of `(ngSubmit)`?

Answer (score 2):

you want to submit the form, through a button click, where the button is out side the form.

Following will be your view/html:

```
<div >
  <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit from outside</button>

  <form [formGroup]="fooForm" (ngSubmit)="onNgSubmit()">
    <label>Label One:</label>
    <input formControlName = "fieldOne">

    <label>Label Two:</label>
    <input formControlName = "fieldTwo">

  </form>
</div>
```

Now in the controller,
when you click the button, call the method tied with ngSubmit event.

```
export class YourComponent  {
  public fooForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.fooForm = new FormGroup({
      'fieldOne':new FormControl('value-one'),
      'fieldTwo':new FormControl('value-two')
    });
  }

  public onSubmit(){
    console.log("submitting from out side the form");
    this.onNgSubmit();
  }

  public onNgSubmit(){
    console.log(this.fooForm.value);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-submit-reactive-form-out-side-submitt-button)

Comment: Please add demo on stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-submit-reactive-form-out-side-submitt-button. I have also added in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

the easy one to add the button inside the form as

If that's not the way that you want to put the button, you have to make other approach.

you have to take advantage of the reactive forms, and in your code

```
func(){ 
    if(this.ngForm.valid){ 
        const formValues = this.ngForm.value;
        this.http.post(url,formValues).subscribe(x => { ... })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answered. Is it possible call submit with ViewChild?

Comment: The base of angular is to avoid to get the basic behaviours and implement those in the controller, but don't know with the definition of the driven template form.
But try @ViewChild("form") formE;
Give it a try with a console.log(this.formE), if appears the tag of the form. maybe. :)